# Creating jar for running MapReduce on Hadoop 1.2.1

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to Hadoop and I have just setup Hadoop 1.2.1 on my Mac laptop (Mavericks). I then created a simple WordCount project in IntelliJ IDEA and was able to run the code on a dummy text file. I am having trouble with successfully creating a jar file which will replicate my execution through the IDE. I get the following error:

```
java -jar ./out/artifacts/WordCount_jar/WordCount.jar test.txt out [19:35:21]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:146)
    at neu.cs.parallelprogramming.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more
FAIL: 1
```

Could anyone let me know what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have to specify your class (which implements the Map/Reduce function).
E.g., `$ java -jar ./WordCount.jar classWordCount input.txt output`
or `$ hadoop jar yourprogram.jar **yourclass** inputpath outputpath`

Comment: Try to comment your guesses